# Kendo Grid In a Kendo Grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am displaying Grid and using detailTemplate to expandRow. But when expand the row, I want to pass the row ID and get datasource and display another grid.

I think detailTemplate won't work in this case. How can I do this ?

Here is my Code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
               var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                   pageSize: 20,
                   data: [
                     { id: "1", name: "Andrew", age: "30" },
                     { id: "2", name: "Robert", age: "29" },
                     { id: "3", name: "Frank", age: "35" }
                   ],
                   autoSync: true,
                   schema: {
                       model: {
                         id: "id",
                         fields: {
                            id: { editable: false, nullable: true, type: "number" },
                            name: { editable: false },
                            age: { 
                                validation: { min: 0, required: true },
                                editable: true, 
                                nullable: true,
                                type: "number"
                            }
                         }
                       }
                   }
                });

                $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                    dataSource: dataSource,
                    pageable: true,
                    height: 550,
                    editable: "inline",
                    columns: [
                        { field: "name",title: "Name" },
                        { field: "age", title: "Age", width: "180px"},
                        { command: ["edit"] }
                    ],
                            detailTemplate: "<div>Name: #: name #</div><div>Age: #: age #</div>"
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked this demo from Kendo UI ?

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/detailtemplate

Similar to your scenario, detail grid is created in *detailInit* function and data for detail grid is filtered for the current employee using *e.data.EmployeeID*